# Substitution failure causes a compile error

Tags: templates, c++17, sfinae

I'm trying to get a better understanding of SFINAE, and have noticed that the following code yields a compile error if the first `enable_if` that checks whether the non-type parameter `g` has a function type is commented out.

```
#include <type_traits>

// Require that a function have a return type of void
template <typename T>
struct ReturnTypeHelper 
{};

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct ReturnTypeHelper<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};

template <typename T>
struct ReturnVoid : std::is_same<typename ReturnTypeHelper<T>::type, void> 
{};

enum class moo {
    yes,
    no,
};

// First candidate
template <auto f, moo m = moo::yes>
void foo() {}

// Second candidate
// Compile error if the first enable_if is commented out
template <auto f, auto g, moo m = moo::yes,
          // Require that g be a function
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(g)>>, void>* = nullptr,
          // Require that g have a return type of void
          std::enable_if_t<ReturnVoid<typename std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(g)>>::value, void>* = nullptr>
void foo() {}

void p() {}

int main()
{
    foo<p, moo::yes>();

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct ReturnVoid<moo>':
<source>:32:101:   required by substitution of 'template<auto f, auto g, moo m, std::enable_if_t<ReturnVoid<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype (g)>::type>::value, void>* <anonymous> > void foo() [with auto f = p; auto g = moo::yes; moo m = moo::yes; std::enable_if_t<ReturnVoid<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype (g)>::type>::value, void>* <anonymous> = <missing>]'
<source>:39:21:   required from here
<source>:14:8: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct ReturnTypeHelper<moo>'
   14 | struct ReturnVoid : std::is_same<typename ReturnTypeHelper<T>::type, void>
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

For template candidate 2 and the function call `foo<p, moo::yes>()`, since `moo::yes` is not a function type, the primary template of `struct ReturnTypeHelper` is chosen, which does not have the `type` member. But in case of this failure, why doesn't the compiler simply choose template candidate 1, but instead reports this error?

Update: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hn5Yn77G5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe:

```
constexpr bool a = ReturnVoid<void()>::value; // true
constexpr bool b = ReturnVoid<int()>::value; // false
constexpr bool c = ReturnVoid<int>::value; // compilation error
```

Now see [SFINAE on cpperefertence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type or its template parameter types or its explicit specifier (since C++20) are SFINAE errors. If the evaluation of a substituted type/expression causes a side-effect such as instantiation of some template specialization, generation of an implicitly-defined member function, etc, errors in those side-effects are treated as hard errors.

So this is exactly that. You need to rewrite `ReturnVoid` such that `ReturnVoid<int>::value` is `false`, not a compilation error. The simplest way is to change the default `ReturnTypeHelper` to

```
template <typename T>
struct ReturnTypeHelper 
{ using type = void(); };
```

(No function can return `void()`, which is another function)